# How to implement a item whose type is derived from a class constructor's arguments

Tags: typescript

How to implement a item whose type is derived from a class constructor's arguments? Is typescript support it? If not, why?

```js
class Toolbar { 
  constructor(adit: string, options: { container: stirng }) { }
}

type ModudleSetting<T extends object = {}> = [
  { new(adit: string, options: T): any },
  T,
]

function registerMoudle(moduleSetting: ModudleSetting) { 
}

registerMoudle([Toolbar, { a: 'asdasd' }])
```

I expect the type of `{ a: 'asdasd' }` is `{ container: stirng }`, but it is not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to make your `registerModule` generic:

```
function registerMoudle<T extends object = {}>(moduleSetting: ModudleSetting<T>) {}
```

[play](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=class%20Toolbar%20%7B%20%0D%0A%20%20constructor(adit%3A%20string%2C%20options%3A%20%7Bcontainer%3A%20string%7D)%20%7B%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20ModudleSetting%3CT%20extends%20object%20%3D%20%7B%7D%3E%20%3D%20%5B%0D%0A%20%20%7B%20new(adit%3A%20string%2C%20options%3A%20T)%3A%20any%20%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20T%2C%0D%0A%5D%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20registerMoudle%3CT%20extends%20object%20%3D%20%7B%7D%3E(moduleSetting%3A%20ModudleSetting%3CT%3E)%20%7B%20%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0AregisterMoudle(%5BToolbar%2C%20%7B%20container%3A%20'1'%20%7D%5D))